# Is it crazy to rely solely on backend validations to validate forms on the front end?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, html, validation

I'm writing some form views in my Rails 3 app, and I am wondering what others out there might be doing to validate forms on the front end and backend in a DRY way.

Of course, it seems there is no way to get around validating on the back end without rails validations. Knowing that, it doesn't seem very DRY to be writing the same validations on the front end. I've read some other threads about writing validations in 2 places, but unless there is a really good reason to do that, I'd rather not.

Knowing the magic of rails, there is probably a simple, easy way to validate both front in and back end in a DRY way, but I have yet to discover it. Perhaps a validation gem?

So I'm thinking that it would be good to use ajax on my front end that calls a validator method on my User model. For example, my username field on the client end listens for jquery keypresses then sends the field contents to my user controller method called 'checkuser' (or something like that). Given that there are 5 or more fields per model, I may end up with a lot of extra field-checking methods in my controllers... too ugly?

Would there be any caveats I should know about doing it this way? Should I really be concerned about those who disable javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be answering this question while coming from ASP.NET background. So please pardon some mistakes if there would be.

In ASP.NET there's a DataAnnotation concept which in short goes like this: for every validated class the metadata is specified in terms of attributes like "Required" or "MinLength(8)" and such. This provides DRY validation - on client these are mapped onto jquery functions automatically and on server these are used by the runtime.

By the way, validating both sides is a must in most cases, since this would prevent excessive server load (when validating on client side) and would prevent incorrect data insert into database (when validating on server side).

After simple googling there seems to exist similar approach in rails as stated in this [so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384506/does-ruby-on-rails-have-client-side-validation-like-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: yeah, i think you're right, keeping the client requests down is probably good enough reason to duplicate code on the client.